# .NET 4.5 -- Send SOAP request via HttpPost

Tags: c#, soap, wsdl, http-post, .net-4.5

I'm writing a .NET application that consumes a SOAP web service.  When I send my SOAP request, I'm getting an error from the server.  One of the things the error says to check is that I'm sending the request via HTTP Post, but I'm not sure how to check this.  I'm building my code off of the WSDL provided by the 3rd party, so I'm calling a function they've defined in order to fire off the request. So how do I tell it to submit via HttpPost?

I briefly decorated my function with this:

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = false)]
```

But I don't think that's what I need.  From what I've read, that's only used when a function can be called directly from a script, and that's not how I've written this.  Also, even if it were useful, such functions apparently default to HttpPost anyway.

I've also wondered if I could set this in the web.config -- maybe in the bindings section?

The examples I've seen so far on sending SOAP requests via POST either apply to .NET 4.0, or they use the **HttpWebRequest** class. But since I have to submit the request via the function defined in the WSDL, I don't think that class would help me...

Any suggestions are really appreciated!

Comment: I would say the first thing you should do is check on how it is sending currently with a tool like Fiddler. If it is in fact sending via GET, then it would be worth trying to change that, but my guess would be that it is already using POST

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that and go from there.

Comment: Did you end up finding out how it was working? If you have a good answer for your own question now that you know more you could post an answer yourself in case another person has the same question down the road

Comment: It seems like some of the XML might have some problems that I didn't initially catch.  You were right -- after some messing around with Fiddler, I finally verified that the submission was already being sent via POST.  If you'd like to repost your comment as an answer, I'd be happy to give you credit!  Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I would do is check how the request is currently being sent using a tool like [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler), which lets you inspect incoming and outgoing web requests. Typically, SOAP WSDLs are written to use `GET` or `POST` as needed, so it shouldn't be something that you have to change.

If it is in fact sending as a GET request, then that is something that would be worth fixing, but I suspect it isn't. More likely it's some other issue with the request, and the warning you're getting is just a generic hint, and not specific to what's wrong with your request.